# intelXDK and choice of database

Tags: sqlite, indexeddb, intel-xdk, web-sql, nosql

I am trying to develop app for mobile using IntelXDK. It is an **offline** quiz app of multiple choice questions. I want to attach database of questions and answers with the app. I tried looking for answer but only came across indexeddb but it does not work for my project. there are websql, sqlite and Nosql which i think can be used for the mobile app. I just need to know which one be beneficial and how to use it in intelXDK?
 Many thanks

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough info to advise.  Can you say more about why indexeddb didn't work for you?  I.e. was there some needed functionality that it did not contain?  Without knowing more, I'd suggest LocalStorage.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer, i have looked into indexeddb and it is the answer to my questions, many thanks.